# ES Multiple must query

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use multi must query but I get following error.
Duplicate key "must" syntax error.
The result should be fanta and cola.
How can I get this datas?

Must be like following results:
1:Coca Cola
2:Fanta

```
  {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
             {
                "match": {
                  "productName":"Coca Cola"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "productCode": "Coke"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "created_date": "2018-06-10"
                }
              }
        ],
        "must": [
             {
                "match": {
                  "productName":"Fanta"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "productCode": "Coke"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "created_date": "2018-06-05"
                }
              }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

In mysql:

SELECT * FROM products WHERE (name='Coca Cola' and code='Coke'...) or (name='Fanta'...)

Answer (score 18):

You need to wrap both `must` (i.e. AND) in a `should` (i.e. OR) like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "productName": "Coca Cola"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "productCode": "Coke"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "created_date": "2018-06-10"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "productName": "Fanta"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "productCode": "Coke"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "created_date": "2018-06-05"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: u saved my time..

Answer (score 2):

I get some insights from a post of elastic official forum, the basic structure is as follow:

```
{
      bool
            must
                bool
                    must
                            condition1
                            condition2
                bool
                    should
                            condition3
                            condition4
                bool
                    should
                            condition5
                            condition6
}
```

[elastic forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-execute-must-and-should-query-that-matches-an-individual-nested-field/239648/4?u=yangbin_zhou)